# How to run react-styleguidist with expo "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs, expo

I want to use react-styleguidist with expo for the web development of react-native components.

So far, I have the following when I run `npm run styleguide`:

```js
./node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/index.js 124:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (124:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| class SafeView extends Component {
>   static setStatusBarHeight = height => {
|     _customStatusBarHeight = height;
|   };
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/index.js 25:11-49
 @ ./node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js
 @ ./src/core/AppCore.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/styleguide-loader.js!./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js
 @ multi ./styleguide/setup.js ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
```

I use expo and never had to configure webpack myself in the expo project. What else do I need to add in the default react-styleguidist webpack config in order to run react styleguidist with expo?

Comment: Dimitri,

Did you ever have luck configuring webpack for expo? Running into this same issue....